# UICollectionViewCell which is reused can't be selected

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

When I try to tap all `collectionViewCell`s from top to bottom, lower cells which is probably reused can't be tapped.
I guess the cells is reused with selection condition.

How do I fix it?

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(106, 106);

    collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
    [collectionView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    collectionView.delegate = self;
    collectionView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:collectionView];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
}
```

CustomCell.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `-collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`, call `[self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` to deselect the cell so that in case it gets reused, the selection won't be passed on to be reused.

Another way of doing this is to have your model track whether it is selected or not so that you can set the `selected` state in `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`.